# IcCube - incremental load - new date not loaded

Tags: iccube

I am using the incremental load option for loading a schema and it calculates new rows (new data).
But the new data for a new date is not displayed properly.

The date dimension is using the default time dimension.
After an incremental load the new data is not mapped to a new date.
If there is a new data for an old date the data is mapped correctly.
The new date is not even shown in the report.

How can the new dates be shown in the reports?

Cheers J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As incremental load of dimensions is not supported yet you cannot see the new date (and its associated facts). We're currently investigating this feature (http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-281).

Hope that helps.